# pattern match,"::" unapply confusion

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and when study the pattern match part, i got confused.

```
val hd::tail = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

After execute this code, hd will be Int = 1 , and tail will be List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5).
And this code equals to:

```
val ::(hd,tail) = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I learned that this code is pattern match and it calls unapply method actually.
But when I write code in this way, compiled error:

```
val result = ::.unapply(List(1,2,3,4,5))
```

It says method parameter type mismatch. The unapply method of "::" need a "::[?]"

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: It may be because `(hd,tail)` is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type mismatch error is because `::.unapply` takes an instance of `::[T]` rather than an instance of the more general type `List[T]`.
Scala will automatically add the matching against the actual type. 
In other words, my understanding is that when you do this:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val hd::tail = list
```

the compiler generates something akin to this:

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val (hd, tail) = 
  ::.unapply(
    // First match to test against input type
    // (necessary as the static type of `list` is `List[Int]`
    // so we don't know until runtime if it is an instance of `::[Int]`
    // or an instance of `Nil`)
    list match { 
      case nonEmptyList: ::[Int] => nonEmptyList 
      case _ => throw new MatchError 
    }
  ) match { // Second match to test against result of `::`.unapply
    case Some( result ) => result
    case _ => throw new MatchError 
  }
```

Comment: +1 for the details, ty.  Can the two matches be collapsed into one?  `case Some(nonEmptyResult : ::[Int]) => nonEmptyResult`

Comment: Accepted. But I'm still wondering this compiler generation is applied for all pattern matching or just for the List situation?

Comment: Always. As soon as the static input type is a sub-type of `unapply`'s expected type, this necessarily requires a runtime type check.

Comment: @Richard Sitze: well this is mainly illustrative. In reality all that you should need to know is that a runtime type check will happen. You can disassemble the generated code and see that this is done via a `instanceof`/`checkcast` pair of bytecode instructions (or if you prefer, this is just `if (x.isInstanceOf[::])   ::.unapply(x.asInstanceOf[::]) else throw new MatchError`. Whether this is emitted directly like that, or optimized away by a late compiler pass is currently beyond my knowledge, and really is an implementation detail.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles: OK, here I'm confused again."As soon as the static input type is a sub-type of unapply's expected type", isn't List parent-type of :: ?

Comment: You are confused, and rightly so, because I said exactly the opposite of the truth. Sorry for that. It should have read "... Is a **supertype** of ...". This is in contrast to when the static input type is a subtype of unapply's parameter type, in which case the call is valid as is, pretty much by definiton of what sub typing means. Note that there is a third case: when the static input type and the type of unapply's parameter have no sub typing relationship whatsoever, then the compiler will emit an error as there is no way for the match to ever succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The method signature you have is incorrect. `::` is a case class, so unapply takes an instance of `::`. Here's something closer to what you might be looking for, though typically I don't call `unapply` in code as it's done in a pattern matching scenario:

```
  //Note the type returned by unapply
  val unappliedOption:Option[(Int, List[Int])] = ::.unapply(::(1, List(2, 3, 4, 5)))

  val (hd, tail) = unappliedOption.getOrElse((1, Nil))
```

In pattern matching `unapply` is called automatically for you. Also note that `::` is a non-empty list though it still returns an `option`. So for an instance of `List` we have two options `::` or `Nil`:

```
  List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) match {
    case hd :: tail => println(hd, tail) // calls ::.unapply and returns hd tail if the option is Some
    case hd => println(hd) //Default case Nil
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm wondering the theory of pattern match. The  book says pattern match calls unapply method in fact. So the 3 lines  code in my questions should be the same, but the third compiled failed which makes me really confused.

Comment: `::.unapply` takes a case class `::`. In your example, you give it a `List` which could be empty unlike `::` which is non-empty. In all case classes `unapply` takes an instance of the case class so you can get back whats contained in the case class. If you look at the definition of `::` it extends `List`, just like `Nil` extends `List`.

Comment: Then why does first and second lines of code work? Don't they also call the unapply method with a List?

Comment: Yes, you'll get a match error if you call it with an empty list `val hd::tail = List()`. It's like my second example without the default case to handle `Nil`.

Comment: So when code written in pattern match style like val hd::tail = List(1,2,3), the compiler first cast List to :: then call the unapply method?

Comment: At runtime the object `List(1, 2, 3)` is checked to see if it's an instance of `::` and compatible with it's unapply method. In this case, `List(1, 2, 3)` is an instance of `::` so `unapply` is called and the head and tail are extracted.